# how to store payment to multiple tables in database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Here are my ***current relations***,

```
 1. The student can join multiple clubs
 2. The student can join multiple events
 3. The student can make payment for club membership
 4. The student can make payment for event fees
```

Here is my ***db for payment***

```
 1. Club
 2. Event
 3. Payment
```

Right now, this is the data model i have in mind but it seems off

```
Clubs table
club_id
club_name
membership_fees
description
...

Events table
event_id
event_name
event_fees
date
venue
...

Payments table
club_id
event_id
user_id
amount
payment_method
...
```

If the user pay fees for the club, event_id will be 0, if user pay for event fees, club_id will be 0. Is this the right way to do it? I wanna be able to query the payment history all in one table. Also, I'll be using laravel for the project

Comment: I see 'wanna' and just move on to the next question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship between both clubs and events are against the *user*, not each other. Also, as both relationships are many-to-many, you would benefit from two [bridging tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity); one between users and clubs, and the other between users and events:

#### `user_clubs` table:

```
user_id  |  club_id   |  payment_method
---------------------------------------
    1    |     1      |  'Visa'
    2    |     1      |  'Visa'
    2    |     2      |  'Mastercard'
```

#### `user_events` table:

```
user_id  |  club_id   |  payment_method
---------------------------------------
    1    |     1      |  'Visa'
    2    |     1      |  'Visa'
    2    |     2      |  'Mastercard'
```

<sup>These are in addition to `user`, `clubs` and `events` tables.</sup>

As you can see, this allows users to join multiple clubs and attend multiple events, while also allowing clubs and events to host multiple users. This also completely eliminates the need for the `payment` table entirely, by shifting the only missing column (`payment_method`) onto the two bridging tables. The `membership_fees` map out to the `amount`, so it is no longer needed.

From here, you can query **all** of the relevant information about a particular user (or club / event) by *joining* the tables together in your query. For example, if you want all info about a user:

```
SELECT * FROM user
         INNER JOIN user_clubs ON user.id = user_clubs.user_id
         INNER JOIN clubs ON user_clubs.club_id = clubs.id
         INNER JOIN user_events ON user.id = user_events.user_id
         INNER JOIN events ON user_events.user_id = club.id
WHERE user.id = '1'
```

This will give you all information about a user; the clubs they belong to, the events they attend, the respective fees, and how the user paid those fees.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is right way and while you fetch the record you need 2 relationship functions in your model one for event and another one for club.

Answer (score 0):

If i think on deepser side of DATABASE DESIGN.  The database design is bad on my opinion.

I suggest that your payment should be simple.

```
transaction_id
user_id
transaction_code
amount
payment_method
notes_description
transaction_datetime
```

Transaction code should be an ID or CODE to "categorize" the what type of payment that is.

With that in mind, You can create as many instances of events, groups, class, membership, etc.. whatever you like. Just by adding new CODE or ID.  No problem.  Centralizing your payments in one table.